# How to connect to production database from mobile device - Meteor?

Tags: android, ios, database, mobile, meteor

The rendered app for Android/iOS from meteor uses the local database. How do I make the app to connect to the database that is used by my webapp?

Or,
How do I connect my mobile app database to the app deployed on meteor server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a meteor package for writing REST APIs:

https://github.com/krose72205/meteor-restivus

The README has a very good example on how to develop for it. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think, Web Services are what you are looking for. ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lU7t5BoxxOA)).

Comment: No. I do not wish to embed it in a native app. I just want access to a remote database for the app which was rendered using Meteor/Cordova. Right now, the app is using the local mongo db. But, I'm unabble to connect to the remote db of my webapp.